# How to use for loop in linux to count and print out a group of words

Tags: linux, loops, count

I'm trying to learn Linux and its commands but I have one doubt that I couldn't find any response...

I need to search and count a few words (ex. cats, dogs, fish) inside a range of files in a specific time (ex.: 10:00-11:00), but I don't know how to proceed with.

I was trying to use a for-loop to make this easier but I don't know how to separate and print out the name files with a word that I am looking for. Ex:

```
=======file_10:01 dogs 10 results
=======file_10:01 cats 231 results
```

and so on...

This is the code that I am executing:

```
for i in `filename_time*`; do
    echo "==================== $i"
    zcat $i | grep -c "dogs"
done
```

Besides that, is it possible to search for words that not contain inside my loop and print out these words?

I am really new to this and would be very glad if somebody could help me with this "easy" question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a hard requirement for your command's output to look like this:

```
=======file_10:01 dogs 10 results
=======file_10:01 cats 231 results
```

And you need to print only the number of lines that have text matching your word, then you should execute something like this:

```
for i in filename_time*; do                 # do globbing like this
    for word in dogs cats; do               # list of words to search for
        n=`zcat $i | grep -c "$word"`       # get n first
        echo "=======$i $word $n results"   # now print the spec
    done
done
```

If, however, you need to print the number of times a word appears in the file then you have to tokenize the words on each line of a file, write each token on a separate line, and then execute the `grep`. In other words, you have to insert another command in the pipeline to tokenize words on each line written by `zcat`. And if you do not want `dogstand` to match `dogs`, then you would also have to change the `grep` command to be this:

```
grep -c "^$word\\$"
```

The `awk` command should be able to tokenize words on a line. Using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22929935/1707353) as an example, you would then write the pipeline like this:

```
zcat $i | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s\n", $i}}' | grep -c "^$word\\$"
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot!

But I have another question there is a way to see other words that doesn't match my search and are inside the files? Ex. spider or shark

Thank you again!

Comment: You may want to try `grep -vc` which gives count of inverse result list.